# Use of purrr's "modify_if" with a function

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to apply the `discretize_rgr` function ([here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/funModeling/versions/1.7/topics/discretize_rgr)) of the package `funModeling` to multiple columns of a dataframe.

For a single column, it is working for me in this way:

```
discretize_rgr(input = df.div$to_be_discretized, target = df.div$TARGET, max_n_bins=10)
```

So, I'm trying to use the `purrr` package to manage multiple columns in this way:

```
df.div %>%
      modify_if( is.numeric, ~ discretize_rgr(., target = df.div$TARGET, max_n_bins=10))
```

but I'm get the following error:

> Error in order(fpoints_top) : argument 1 is not a vector

What's wrong?

**UPDATE (example data)**

```
structure(list(to_be_discretized = c(0.0152096300012854, 0.0132660373578711, 
0.014699121782711, 0.0157102877064037, 0.0197417484744586, 0.019651999420645
), TARGET = c(27136, 30048, 34840, 138812, 191088, 240370)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: `df %>%
  modify_if(is.numeric, ~ discretize_rgr(., target = df$TARGET, max_n_bins=10))` seems to work on your sample data without any errors.

Comment: it seems that it works fine with a tibble, but I got an error using a dataframe... I have to investigate more